# Moving the marble in the marble maze game

Tags: python

I am working on this Marble maze game on sense hat. https://trinket.io/sense-hat

The task is that i have to create a marble randomly and then move it.

Here is the code:

```
'''Importing useful packages'''
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import random
sense = SenseHat()

'''color to be used in the game'''
r = (255, 0, 0)
b = (0, 0, 0)
g = (0, 255, 0) 
w = (255, 255, 255)


maze =        [[r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r],
              [r,b,r,r,r,r,r,r],
              [r,b,b,b,b,b,b,r],
              [r,r,r,r,r,r,b,r],
              [r,b,r,r,r,r,b,r],
              [r,b,b,b,b,b,b,r],
              [r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r],
              [r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r]]


def generate_marble(maze): # HELP
  x_m = randint(0, 7)
  y_m = randint(0, 7)
  while maze[y_m][x_m] == r :
    x_m = randint(0, 7)
    y_m = randint(0, 7)
  maze[y_m][x_m] = w

def move_marble(pitch,roll,x_m,y_m):
    new_x = x_m
    new_y = y_m
    if 1 < pitch < 179:
        new_x -= 1
    elif 359 > pitch > 181:
        new_x += 1
    #return new_x, new_y
    return x_m,y_m


generate_marble(maze)
time = 0
while True:
  time += 1
  print(time)
  pitch = sense.get_orientation()['pitch']
  roll = sense.get_orientation()['roll']
  x_m,y_m = move_marble(pitch,roll,x_m,y_m)
  sense.set_pixels(sum(maze,[]))
  sleep(0.5)
```

I am getting the following error: **NameError: name 'x_m' is not defined on line 52 in main.py**

Comment: Do  `x_m,y_m = generate_marble(maze)`

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable on line 44 in main.py"

Comment: Don't know where this is and I'm not gonna debug your code ;)

Comment: This refers to the same line which you asked me to update, which is "generate_marble(maze)".

Comment: generate method should `return x_m,y_m`

Comment: Thanks. I can now generate the marble using this method but even after several attempts, I am not able to move it.